# Tile map with character and interaction

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making a program where you bassicly move from tile to tile in windows forms. So in order to do that, I wanted to use panels each panel has a tag. To detect collision. The goal is to be able to find creatures that randomly spawn somehow i don't how to do that.

So I have an image of my map. and I divided into multiple tiles. So using this code I create the pictureboxes needed for the tile map but I want to **add a character that is one tile big how can I do that???**
**I also want to be able to move around that character tag how would i fix that. 
And also give the tiles a tag so the character can't go there.**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
int tileWidth = 30;
int tileHeight = 30;
int tileRows = 30;
int tileCols = 30;

using (Bitmap sourceBmp = new Bitmap("D:\\900x900.jpg"))
{
    Size s = new Size(tileWidth, tileHeight);
    Rectangle destRect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, s);
    for (int row = 0; row < tileRows; row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < tileCols; col++)
        {
            PictureBox p = new PictureBox();
            p.Size = s;
            Point loc = new Point(tileWidth * col, tileHeight * row);
            Rectangle srcRect = new Rectangle(loc, s);
            Bitmap tile = new Bitmap(tileWidth, tileHeight);
            Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(tile);
            G.DrawImage(sourceBmp, destRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            p.Image = tile;
            p.Location = loc;
            p.Tag = loc;
            p.Name = String.Format("Col={0:00}-Row={1:00}", col, row);
            // p.MouseDown += p_MouseDown;
            // p.MouseUp += p_MouseUp;
            // p.MouseMove += p_MouseMove;
            this.Controls.Add(p);
        }
}
```

}

Comment: I would think a better approach might be to create pictureboxes for each object rather than each tile. Then you could just move the picturebox when the object (player, enemy, whatever) moves.

Comment: What do you mean by each object? As here I have done an image that gets cut up into smaller pictureboxes as a tiles. Then I want to add a character as a tile and move it around. Wouldn't it still work? Just don't know how to fix it

Comment: You're going to be doing a lot of redrawing tiles that way. Every time an object moves, you'll have to redraw the picturebox where they're moving from (so only the background remains) and the picturebox where they're moving to (to include the object that moved on top of the background). However, if you just draw the background once and then place the objects as pictureboxes, all you have to do is move the picturebox and tell the background to refresh.

Comment: Oh i get what u mean but how would the coding be as im not that good at the coding part. do u have an example. And how would i go around moving pictureboxes coding wise

Comment: You just assign the picturebox's Location property a new Point object with the updated position.

Comment: Just thinking if i want to have a map then if i go right out of the map i want to change the map would it be possible? Also if i use this system how would i go around giving monsters and player stats. And the moving of pictureboxes can it be done by binding it to keyboard buttons ? if so how?

Comment: Yes, all those things are possible, but it's way too much to talk about here. Give them a shot and if you get stuck on any one thing, ask about it here in a new question.

Comment: Just one thing... Do you mean to have an big picturebox where i have this map and then place smaller pcitureboxes as objects? And if i don´t have an tilesystem wouldn't the moving around part get weird'??? since they cant follow a path. Also what do you mean by tell the background to refresh?

Comment: You will not be able to have proper transparency when a controls is not nested in one control but only overlaps one or more controls!! - Better draw all parts, as has been suppested.. - _Do you mean to have an big picturebox where i have this map and then place smaller pcitureboxes as objects?_ Yes!  - _And if i don´t have an tilesystem wouldn't the moving around part get weird'??? since they cant follow a path._ you control the movement by controlling what happens when the user presses the buttons or moves the mose; you can always enforce going only in one direction or only in steps..